# Replace list in master activity with another list and remove old list from view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

When staring my app a list (list_main) is displayed in the master fragment. There is also a 2nd list fragment that is supposed to open when I clicking the 1st list item from my main list fragment, however after clicking the 1st list item, the main list fragment DOES disappear but the 2nd list does NOT appear hence the master fragment remains blank. Also when I click the back button, the main list does NOT reappear. Does anyone know why these issues are occurring and how they can be resolved?

**Main Activity XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/master_container"
        android:name="com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.FragmentMainList"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/detail_container"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Main List Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentmainlist">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main List fragment class**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class FragmentMainList extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ListView list_main;

    String[] listContent = {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3"
    };


    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
        list_main = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_main);

        list_main = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listContent);
        list_main.setAdapter(adapter);

        list_main.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (mTwoPane) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++)
                        adapterView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    // change the background color of the selected list view item
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00BCD4"));
                }


                if (position == 0) {
                    if (mTwoPane) {
                        FragmentItem1 newFragment = new FragmentItem1();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        list_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
                        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                        transaction.commit();
                    } else {

                    }
                }

                if (position == 1) {

                }

                if (position == 2) {

                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

**Main Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView list_main;

    String[] listContent = {
            "Station Chooser",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3"
    };

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list_main = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listContent);
        list_main.setAdapter(adapter);

        list_main.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                    if (mTwoPane) {
                        FragmentStationChooser newFragment = new FragmentStationChooser();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


                        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                        transaction.commit();

                    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                    } else {

                    }
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                }
            }
        });

        if (findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Station Chooser fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_linechooser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Station Chooser fragment class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentStationChooser extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_station_chooser, container, false);
    }

}
```

**Station Chooser Activity class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StationChooserActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView list_linechooser;

    String[] listContent = {
            "Line 1",
            "Line 2",
            "Line 3"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_station_chooser);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        list_linechooser = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_linechooser);
        list_linechooser.setAdapter(adapter);

        list_linechooser.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
        });
    }

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            FragmentMainList newFragment = new FragmentMainList();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            list_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment).commit();

            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific problem do you have. What is not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [2nd list to replace 1st list - which method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423343/2nd-list-to-replace-1st-list-which-method)

Comment: Are you sure that `mTwoPane` is `true`? Post the code of `FragmentStationChooser`.

Comment: @MacaronLover did you check that `mTwoPane` is in fact `true`?

Comment: Yeah, but are you sure that it is `true`? Otherwise the transaction never gets executed and it's no wonder why you don't see anything happen.

Comment: post the xml with the id `master_container`

Comment: For clarity, you need to update your post with the updated code. You may keep the old code, but you can clarify the new/updated code with words like "EDIT" , "UPDATE".

Comment: How is the progress so far?  It seems you have few questions on your project. Simply post them or a question into another post. I am seeking aggressively for rep points. Let us know...

Comment: Looking at your post, you don't have any more problems but I think you do. You may add the question to your post with words like EDIT" , "UPDATE. Another, sometimes it is more appropriate to add the problem onto another post, not this one. This is all I am saying to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem why the fragment is not showing upon poping the backstack is that you are trying to inflate that fragment in another fragments id which is this part of the code:

`transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);`

You don't need a whole new activity just to host another fragment which you did in your `FragmentStationChooser`.

Now what you need to do is to have a container to host your fragment in your activity main so instead of having a fragment tag replace it with a container such as relative layout:

replace this:

`<fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/master_container"
        android:name="com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.FragmentMainList"/>`

to

`<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/master_container"/>`

After you do that, In your main activity remove all the listview code and transfer it in to your `FragmentMainList`where you use the view when you inflate it:

`public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
        list_main = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_main);
        .//the logic from your activity main transfered here in the FragmentMainList
        .
        .
        return v;
    }`

Lastly do it the same in your `FragmentStationChooser` and don't use the activity `StationChooserActivity` just remove it from your project

EDIT:

remove the `list_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);` due to the fact the it will be replace by a fragment when it is inflated

EDIT 2:

in the onCreate of your main activity add this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentMainList newFragment = new FragmentMainList();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);    
        transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: After moving my code, I encounter 3 errors. See latest screenshot.

Comment: @MacaronLover the first error should be `v.findViewById` like the above sample, the second error change `this` to `getActivity()`, the third error change to `FragmentMainList.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I now get a warning say Class 'FragmentMainList' is never used.

Comment: Cool. Now, the app does run & not crash but after selecting a list item, the new list does not open in the master fragment but opens in a new window instead (see latest 2 screenshots).

Comment: @MacaronLover maybe you are starting a new activity, try using the code above like the oncreate in the list item click but instead of `FragmentMainList` change it to `FragmentStationChooser`

Comment: OK got it working now. Just got confused with the animations.

Comment: Although there is 1 problem left and that's when I tap other items they don't stay highlighted even though I have the code in my project.

`if (mTwoPane) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++)
                            adapterView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                        // change the background color of the selected list view item
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
                    }`

Comment: @MacaronLover and make sure that you have a data structure/ an array for that

Answer (score 1):

Due to your past comments and my suggestion to move code from **StationChooserActivity**.java to **FragmentStationChooser**

Code for **FragmentStationChooser** class:

```
    String[] listContent = {
            "Line 1",
            "Line 2",
            "Line 3"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_station_chooser, container, false);
        ListView list_linechooser = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_linechooser);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_station_chooser, listContent);
        list_linechooser.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
```

It's a start. I tried my best to understand your post and the issue. Good luck.

Comment: NB: `list_main` is the one I want to disappear from view. Dunno why you are  using `View.VISIBLE` when that list is already there when my app first launches. `list_main` is the list that appears first when my app launches. I want that to be replaced by `list_linechooser` so that `list_linechooser` appears on the user's device + when the back button is pressed, I want `list_linechooser` to disappear from view and `list_main` to reappear.

Comment: @MacaronLover, Do you realize list_linechooser ListView is declared on another Activity instead of a Fragment, which is a common way? But I m confused that fragment_station_chooser layout xml file is referenced in another file, FragmentStationChooser.java.  Perhaps place the code from StationChooserActivity.java to FragmentStationChooser.

Comment: Yes, I realise that but I also did that for the list_main List View. I've put it in another activity because I want those list items to do other things when clicked. Does that list_linechooser code need to go in my FragmentStationChooser.java file? Can I send you a zip file of my project?

Comment: @MacaronLover, Yes the list_linechooser code should be moved to FragmentStationChooser.java. You have a misunderstanding that a Fragment subclass cannot execute code for the GUI or click events, that is not so. In your case, place all UI operations in a Fragment. IF I have the time, I may update my post with some code per my understanding of your design.

Comment: @MacaronLover, About your code, I would rather you post them into Github website for others to see or update the code in your original post. You may keep adding to your post stating the new code versus old ones.

Comment: After moving the code to FragmentStationChooser.java, 2 errors occur that i don't know how to resolve. A screenshot has been posted and the code has been updated.

Comment: Code posted at the top

Comment: @MacaronLover, Finally I added sample code for possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `StationChooserActivity` is your Main Activity, and there is no other activity. You did not mention that.

The only thing your app would do is display "Line 1", "Line 2", and Line 3 into the Listview, based on array listContent. This is due to code `MyColoringAdapter adapter = new MyColoringAdapter(this,listContent)`.

Another, when user hits the **Back** key, a new Fragment FragmentMainList may be displayed if mTwoPane is true, not sure though. Afterwards I think your app will exit.

Note: The Main Activity does not do much. I don't think that is the intent. You need to determine what to do with it. That is my best advice.

Comment: My main activity code is at the top under **Main Activity class**. The objective of the Main Activity is to show a list (which it already does) and when 'Item 1' is clicked, that list should disappear (which it does) and the other list should appear (which does not happen). That's the main issue I'm having, it doesn't appear and I don't why nor how to resolve that issue.

Comment: Do you know what's wrong with my other error? [Error question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630467/list-fragment-not-appearing-owing-to-no-view-found-for-id-error)